# SVN: delete / revert one file revision

Tags: c#, .net, svn

I would like to delete the the revision of just one file. I've been trying a lot of different ways and also reading some advice here and on google.

I simply want to do like if that single file had never been modified with the last revision.

Is it possible?

Comment: In Subversion, you can't change history (unless you dump and restore, but that seems extreme). The best you can do is to commit a "fixed" version on top of it.

Comment: svnadmin dump / dumpfilter / import into new repository to "really" remove it. Otherwise something like "Revert changes from this revision" using TortoiseSVN when viewing the log and then commit that change.

Comment: @crashmstr: I got mad trying in many ways to "Revert changes from this revision".. I tried for hours with merge, get specific version and so on..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use TortoiseSVN: just right click the file -> `show log`. Go to revision you want to revert -> right click on revision an `revert changes form this revision`. After that you have to perform a commit to bring your changes to the repository.